# How much large file we can upload to Azure file share in a single shot in .net core 3.1

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I need to upload a large file (140 mb) to Azure file share. Please let me know how much large file I can upload using FileShareClient upload method in C#

Comment: Have you tried to upload and received an error? Why don't you upload / download to and from using Azure Blob storage?.... 'using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob'

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of a file in a File Share is 4 TiB ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file)) so you can definitely store a 140MB file in Azure File Share.

However you cannot upload a 140MB file in Azure File Share in a single shot. For that you will need to upload it in chunks where each chunk cannot be more than 4MB ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-range)).

Comment: Using the Fileshareclient upload method I checked that I am able to upload a large file (57 mb) in a single shot. After this size it is taking much time to upload. That's why I asked maximum how much large file I can upload  in a single shot